# Looking for Failover Cluster for Scientific Linux and nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, cluster, high-availability, failover

here is what I'm trying:

- two instances of SL7.1 with nginx as reverseproxy
- no shared filesystem
- shared resources:

  - virtual IP
  - running nginx service

I already tried keepalived and corosync + pacemaker.

keepalived had problems with vrrp-scripts: There was a bug that the script didnt check, if the service nginx is running. So the failover only worked when the server was shutdown.

corosync + pacemaker had the problems that I needed to configure fencing with fence-agents-vmware-soap which is not possible here (comapany policys). The reverseproxy is located in the DMZ and for communication with the VMWare-Host, the Firewall had to be changed which was no declined.

Do you have hints, howtos, etc. for doing the whole thing again?

Thanks

Comment: "Had problems" is not useful info, and you might want to specify what your company policies forbid so people don't waste time recommending stuff.

Comment: It will probably be easier to change the company policy so that you can actually deploy something correctly.

Comment: So you are saying, pacemaker with corosync is state of the art and best practice?

Comment: Yes, that's the expected deployment method for RHEL 7 and its derivatives such as Scientific Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Considering Red Hat has a [guide for EL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/High_Availability_Add-On_Administration/ch-startup-HAAA.html) that walks you through most of this using Corosync and Pacemaker, your problem (fencing) is political and not technical...

There may be another fencing method that could be used here. But that's probably the best option to pursue.